# HTTPS proxy CONNECT issue

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

I am trying to make a proxy which works with HTTPS requests. The proxy I want to make just needs to tunnel and packets and don't disturb them. So I tried to make a connection between the browser and the proxy and the browser sends a CONNECT request to google for example and then I made a new socket that creates its own connect request to the same host and port but google for example returns a BAD REQUEST method. what should I do?

I just want to make a simple tunneling proxy to HTTPS using `httplib` and `sockets`. Here's my code:

```
import socket
```

from Packet import *
import httplib

class SockClient:

```
def __init__(self,sock,addr):
    print "[*]New client has joined! ["+str(addr)+"]"
    self.__sock = sock
    self.__addr = str(addr)
    self.__target = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.__open = True

def Process(self , Socklist , Clientlist):
    print "[*]Receiving data. ["+self.__addr+"]"

    try:
        data = self.__sock.recv(1024)
    except:
        print "***WTF BROWSER***"
        print "[*]Closing connection with target. ["+self.__addr+"]"
        print "------------------------------------------------- ["+self.__addr+"]"
        self.__target.close()
        self.__sock.close()
        Socklist.remove(self.__sock)
        Clientlist.remove(self)
        self.__open = True
        return 1

    print "[*]Data received. ["+self.__addr+"]"
    print "[*]Data:\r\n" + data
    print "[*]Analyzing data. ["+self.__addr+"]"

    if data == "":
        print "[*]Client closed connection. ["+self.__addr+"]"
        print "[*]Closing connections with target. ["+self.__addr+"]"
        print "------------------------------------------------- ["+self.__addr+"]"
        self.__target.close()
        self.__sock.close()
        Socklist.remove(self.__sock)
        Clientlist.remove(self)
        self.__open = True
        return 1

    print "[*]Creating packet. ["+self.__addr+"]"
    packet = Packet(data)
    print "[*]Packet created. ["+self.__addr+"]"
    print "[*]Connecting to target. ["+self.__addr+"]"

    if self.__open:
            self.__target.connect((packet.GetHost() , packet.GetPort()))
            if packet.GetRequest() == "CONNECT":
                #send 200 ok packet to client and closes connections.
                self.__sock.send("HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established\r\nProxy-Agent: Gladis\r\n\r\n")
                print "SEND 200 OK PLZ"
                print "[*]Closing connections with client and target. ["+self.__addr+"]"
                print "------------------------------------------------- ["+self.__addr+"]"
                self.__target.close()
                self.__sock.close()
                Socklist.remove(self.__sock)
                Clientlist.remove(self)
                self.__open = True
                return 1


    '''
    try:
        if self.__open:
            if packet.GetPort() == 443:
                self.__target = httplib.HTTPSConnection(packet.GetHost(),443)
                if packet.GetRequest() == "CONNECT":
                    #send 200 ok packet to client and closes connections.
                    self.__target.connect()
                    resp = self.__target.getresponse()
                    print resp.status , resp.reason
                    page = resp.read()
                    print page
                    self.__sock.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: "+str(len(page))+"\r\n\r\n" + page)
                    print "SEND 200 OK PLZ"
                    print "[*]Closing connections with client and target. ["+self.__addr+"]"
                    print "------------------------------------------------- ["+self.__addr+"]"
                    self.__target.close()
                    self.__sock.close()
                    Socklist.remove(self.__sock)
                    Clientlist.remove(self)
                    self.__open = True
                    return 1

            else:
                self.__target.connect((packet.GetHost() , packet.GetPort()))
        self.__open = False
    except:
        print "***COULDNT MAKE CONNECTION WITH TARGET***"
        print "[*]Closing connections with client. ["+self.__addr+"]"
        print "------------------------------------------------- ["+self.__addr+"]"
        self.__target.close()
        self.__sock.close()
        Socklist.remove(self.__sock)
        Clientlist.remove(self)
        self.__open = True
        return 1
    '''

    print "[*]Connection estabished. ["+self.__addr+"]"
    print "[*]Sending packet to target. ["+self.__addr+"]"

    try:
        self.__target.send(packet.GetPacket())
    except:
        print "[*]Sending packet failed. ["+self.__addr+"]"
        print "[*]Closing connections with client. ["+self.__addr+"]"
        print "------------------------------------------------- ["+self.__addr+"]"
        self.__target.close()
        self.__sock.close()
        Socklist.remove(self.__sock)
        Clientlist.remove(self)
        self.__open = True
        return 1

    print "[*]Packet sent. ["+self.__addr+"]"
    print "[*]Waiting for response. ["+self.__addr+"]"

    try:
        reply = self.__target.recv(8192)
    except:
        print "***ERROR IN RECV***"
        print "[*]Closing connections with client and server. ["+self.__addr+"]"
        print "------------------------------------------------- ["+self.__addr+"]"
        self.__target.close()
        self.__sock.close()
        Socklist.remove(self.__sock)
        Clientlist.remove(self)
        self.__open = True
        return 1

    print "[*]Reply received. ["+self.__addr+"]"
    print "[*]Reply:\r\n"+ reply
    print "[*]Analyzing reply. ["+self.__addr+"]"

    if reply == "":
        print "[*]Target closed connection. ["+self.__addr+"]"
        print "[*]Closing connection with client. ["+self.__addr+"]"
        print "------------------------------------------------- ["+self.__addr+"]"
        self.__target.close()
        self.__sock.close()
        Socklist.remove(self.__sock)
        Clientlist.remove(self)
        self.__open = True
        return 1


    print "[*]Sending reply to client. ["+self.__addr+"]"

    try:
        self.__sock.send(reply)
    except:
        print "***ERROR IN SEND***"
        print "[*]Closing connection with target. ["+self.__addr+"]"
        print "------------------------------------------------- ["+self.__addr+"]"
        self.__target.close()
        self.__sock.close()
        Socklist.remove(self.__sock)
        Clientlist.remove(self)
        self.__open = True
        return 1
    print "[*]Reply sent. ["+self.__addr+"]"

    print "[*]Closing connections with client and server[Done!]. ["+self.__addr+"]"
    self.__target.close()
    self.__sock.close()
    Socklist.remove(self.__sock)
    Clientlist.remove(self)
    print "------------------------------------------------- ["+self.__addr+"]"

def GetSock(self):
    return self.__sock
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CONNECT method is only used between client and proxy to make the proxy create a tunnel, i.e it specifies the final target of the tunnel.  Once the TCP connection to the server given in the CONNECT request is established the proxy sends a positive response to the CONNECT request. After that all data between client and proxy are simply transferred to the server and back. The CONNECT request itself is not forwarded to the server.

For the exact details please see [RFC 2817](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2817).

Comment: Please summarize the relevant details in the link.

Comment: The proxy is just a tunnel. The CONNECT method is sent from the browser to a specific host. I am just trying to get the packets from the browser through the proxy to the server.

Comment: @Nostalgia72: see the edited response - the CONNECT is only done between client and proxy, not between proxy and server.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich I did what you said and the browser closes the connection after that. The browser sent a CONNECT request to the proxy and the proxy established a TCP connection with the server but when the proxy responded to the browser with "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established\r\nProxy-Agent: Gladis" the browser closed the connection. or stopped sending anymore packets.

Comment: @Nostalgia72: please update the code to reflect what you did. And note that any HTTP request and response header must end with `\r\n\r\n` which seems to be not the case in your code.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich Just updated it. and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Nostalgia72: you should not  create a HTTPSConnection but just a TCP connection. And you should get the target for the connection from the CONNECT request. I really recommend reading the RFC.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich I updated the code again and read the RFC but still it dosen't work. The browser stops sending any packets after he gets the answer for the CONNECT request from the proxy.
What should I do ?

Comment: @Nostalgia72: I cannot see that the proxy forwards any data between client and server. You just answer the clients CONNECT request and then immediately close all connections.

Comment: @Nostalgia72: Again: based on the code you immediately close the socket to the client after you've send the response to the CONNECT. You do not transfer any kind of data inside the tunnel but simply close the tunnel directly after you've established it. And if you post code please keep it minimal and don't include all the experiments you've tried as comments.